# Security Permissions Model

Tags: security, permissions

I am developing a desktop application and would like to lock down certain parts for certain users - admins, guests, users, etc. What sort of design patterns are there for implementing a such a permissioning system in a desktop? I can only think of three, but I don't know what they're named (or if they are),

1. 1) Each action performs
   it's own security checking, querying
   a session or a database for the
   appropriate user permissions (common among simple web apps)
2. Each
   action checks with a centralized
   permissioning system saying "Does
   user have x permission", which
   returns some status
3. Before an action is even attempted, it is intercepted by a dispatcher, which performs some lookup of the action to the applicable permission and user's permissions, and prevents the action from even starting when not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were looking for RBAC (Role based acess control). I think there is no clear difference between the concept of access control in desktop application and access control in web application. The difference is only in the implementation. You might want to check out Spring Rich Client Platform which are integrated to Spring Security.
Outside the Spring Security, the design patterns of RBAC that I could recall are :

1. Each user might be directly associated to one or many roles
2. Each role has one or more permission
3. Each user might belong to one or many groups
4. Each group has one or more roles

Other patterns that might be of interest is ACL (access control lists) that we accustomed to in Windows based systems :

1. Each object has an ACL, which shows which user or which group were given access to the object
2. A child object inherits the parent's ACL

Comment: That's not really what I was getting at, but it's a decent complement to the patterns I listed above.

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered similar question for difference between ACL and RBAC, you can check it here.

[What is the exact difference between ACL and RBAC in general?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941767/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-acl-and-rbac-in-general/31958180#31958180)